# PHP Simple XML Xpath Move Up Tree (Parent with Name)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using Xpath with SimpleXML to find child elements like so:

```
$child=$file->xpath('//w:child')[0];
```

If I want to select the parent, I can do:

```
$parent=$child->xpath('..')[0];
```

But what if I want to find a parent or grandparent called "any_parent", at any level of the tree. For example:

```
$any_parent=$child->xpath('any_parent//..')[0];
```

is this possible? I want it to be relative to `$child`. And then move up the tree and select the tag `any_parent`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the `ancestor` axis.

You are looking for the element node named `any_parent`:

```
ancestor::any_parent
```

^ that is the name of the axis (*ancestor*, [*see all*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes)), two colons ("::") and the node test, which is here the element name.

PHP/SimpleXMLElement:

```php
$any_parent = $child->xpath('ancestor::any_parent')[0];
```

---

**Note:** As there can be none or multiple, directly accessing `[0]` may give you unexpected results.

You can provide a default `null` for example to express not finding any node and the position test to express you want the first node specifically:

```php
$any_parent = $child->xpath('ancestor::grandparent[1]')[0] ?? null;
```

or:

```php
[$any_parent] = $child->xpath('ancestor::grandparent[1]') + [null];
```

Comment: Will this work if there is a namespace? For example w:parent, will ancestor::w:parent work? Also, is there differences if you do ./ancestor vs //ancestor vs ancestor?

Comment: Yes, the axis / axes are with namespaces, it is the node-test where you check for the namespace, so yes, `axis::prefix:local-name` works. `./ancestor::*` and `ancestor::*` is effectively the same, `.` is an abbreviation of the context node, $child. `//ancestor` will ruin your result, as `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so you would cross two axes here that includes descendants but you want ancestors (any parent, grandparent, grand-grandparent .... not child, grand-child ...).